# Manga where the mc is reincarnated to another world, and is accidentally transported into a nest of dragons

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, dragons, reincarnation

I'm looking for a black & white manga where the main character is reincarnated to another world, and is accidently sent into a nest of dragons, where he becomes overpowered while killing them all. Later on in the chapter he meets a pack of female wolf demi-humans and saves them from orcs only to find out that one of them is his childhood friend that has reincarnated into the same world as him.

When the hero was given a chance to reincarnate by the god/goddess into another world his main skills where 5x XP boost and Navigator but was accidently sent into a nest of dragons while being transported so he fought them off with his fist while learning magic and fighting from his Navigator skill after that he was given a reward by a spirit of a dragon for defeating his enemies.

I recall that he fights dragons to live, and in doing so, becomes overpowered. Later on, he reunites with his friend who died years ago and reincarnated as a beastman.

mc was killed I don't remember how but he was given a chance to reincarnate by the god/goddess into another world his main skills where 5x XP boost and navigator but was accidently sent into a nest of dragons while being transported so he fought them off with his fist while learning magic and fighting from his navigator skill after that he was given a reward by a spirit of a dragon for defeating his enemies. Later on in the story he meets his childhood friend who was also reincarnated into that world as a silver wolf race. Sorry, that's all I know so far.
I think the name was in Japanese.

Comment: Reincarnated as a Spider, probably. Unless you know for a fact it was a guy and not a girl and was initially reincarnated as a human.

Comment: no man it wasn't that but he was reincarnated as a human.

Comment: Does he get stronger via a level up system? If he's fighting dragons to live, does that mean they appear constantly through the story, and not just in the first few chapters where he becomes strong?

Comment: No just the first few chapters only

Comment: How does the MC kill the dragons? Sword, Spear or another melee weapon? Magic? Summoning a meteor shower to kill everything around him? He fights them to live - does this just mean so they won't kill him, or does he eat them as well?

Comment: he kills them with melee first and after he is done he goes to a dragon shrine where a dragon thanks him for deafeating the enemy and gives him lots of treasure in return of deafeting the enemy

Comment: "My Isekai Life: I Gained a Second Character Class and Became the Strongest Sage in the World" is remarkably close, but also has a huge number of differences. He obliterates a dragon in the first chapter, but only one. He's overpowered before fighting the dragon, not after. He encounters a talking wolf, but there's no indication it's his childhood friend or reincarnated at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Kami no Techigai de Shindara Zumi de Isekai ni Hourikomare Mashita](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/c6sigmh/kami-no-techigai-de-shindara-zumi-de-isekai-ni-hourikomare-mashita)***.

> Tomoya Sadoshima died after a serious accident due to the mismanagment of a Goddess. Then, after regaining consciousness in a pure white world, a woman of divine beauty emerged, she introduces herself as "The Goddess of Creation." The goddess of creation prepared a remedy for his suffering, she offers him to reincarnate into a different world than his own. But it was a world in a war situation with the demon king. And so begins the story of Tomoya and his adventure to defeat the demon king and get the harem he so desires!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this is the correct manga, specifying any plot points that match the description given in the question, and any that don't.

Comment: I don't read Japanese, So I can't swear to specifics of things like the Navigator ability, but I paged through the first chapter, and the protagonist basically gets dropped into a setup of orcs attacking a village, nothing about dragons. Also, fair warning, the first few pages are high on nudity, albeit with Barbie doll anatomy.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly *Death March to the Parallel World Rhapsody*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you add some details about the story to help the asker understand how this matches?  You might want to read [answer].

Comment: Almost certainly not. He levels up from accidentally killing a bunch of dragons at the start and has a navigation skill of sorts, but nothing else matches.