# Manga where the MC is summoned by a goddess and, as soon as he arrives, he defeats dragon; he later arrives at a village and meets a former friend

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, isekai

The main character (MC) is overpowered and, throughout the manga, women who knew him from the other world come to this world to see him (they are heroes). He gets a mansion from an old queen and a strong dragon demi-human maid, as well as all the demi-humans from his childhood friend's village that he saved.

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: black and white

Comment: Was the "strong dragon demi-human maid" the humanoid form of the same dragon he fought near the beginning? If so, this could be _[Moon-led Journey Across Another World](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/ixgbdrq/tsuki-ga-michibiku-isekai-douchuu)_. It features some of the other things you mentioned (like the MC being summoned by a goddess and other people from his world being summoned afterwards), but I can't confirm that it has everything you mentioned yet. Let me know if that is or isn't the one you're looking for, so I can either post it as a proper answer or rule it out of consideration.

Comment: Possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/262587/manga-where-the-mc-is-reincarnated-to-another-world-and-is-accidentally-transpo ? Shares the details of overpowered protagonist, defeating dragon(s), and at least one woman known from before reincarnation. No idea about the mansion or dragon maid.