Isekai manga about a guy who is reincarnated and meets his childhood friend, now a wolf girl
This manga is about a guy who is reincarnated and meets his childhood friend, now a wolf girl, and they sleep together. Also, a few chapters later, his female co-workers were also summoned to that world and were tricked by a different god.

Is this the same story as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/262587 ? That question also mentions a childhood friend wolf after isekai.
